# How to access Material-UI custom theme inside children of ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I want to access the colors that I have set in customized MUI `theme` inside `CustomCheckbox.js` components, and I couldn't find how to do it.

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CustomCheckbox from "./CustomCheckbox";

export default function someFunction(){
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      type: "dark",
      background: {
        default: "#242729",
        paper: "#323638",
    },

  return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CustomCheckbox defaultChecked />
  </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  }, 
}))
```

At the CustomCheckbox component:

```
const CustomCheckbox = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  ....
  return (
     <div className={classes.paper}>
  ....
```